# Define object from other classes

Tags: c++

**I can't define object from other classes under the top class 
Example :**

```
class B; 
class a
{
public:     
    a(){ cout << "a\n"; }
    ~a(){ cout << "~a\n"; }
private:
B ob;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(){ cout << "B\n"; }
    ~B(){ cout << "~B\n"; }
    a ob;
};

int main()
{
    B r;

    system("pause");

}
```

**the problem I can't make an object in class a
even if I write (class B;) above it**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be solved by passing a `B` object pointer into the `a` constructor. If you change the `B` class to contain a *pointer* to `a`, your recursion could be solved. As it is, you are creating an infinite loop, by creating an object `B` that contains an object `a`, which contains an object `B`, and so on.

```
class B
{
public:
    B(a* _ob) : ob(_ob) { cout << "B\n"; }
    ~B(){ cout << "~B\n"; }
    a* ob;
};

int main()
{
    a _a;
    B r(_a);

    system("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your classes are defined recursively.

Your op members are no references, but real objects. So each `a` contains an `B` that contains an `a` that contains an `B` that contains ...

This loop is never ending, so there is no way in creating a B object.